# Does "A::B::C v;" means that A and B are namespaces and C is a class?

Tags: c++, types, syntax, scope, namespaces

When you see an instruction like

```
A::B::C v;
```

in a [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) code, does it mean that `A` and `B` are *namespaces* defined in some header file, and `C` is a class in the *namespace* `B`?

Comment: it means you need to look where `A` and `B` and `C` are declared, because it could be `namespace::namespace::type` or `namespace::type::type` or `type::type::type`

Comment: C could also be the name of a class template

Comment: The correct C++ name for `A::B::C v;` is not an "instruction" but a **definition**, which is a sort of **declaration**. In particular, it's the definition of a variable `v` (assuming the line appears outside a `class`), so `A::B::C` has to be the type of `v`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be following three possibilities:

```
namespace A {
    namespace B {
        using C = int; // some types
    }
}
```

or

```
namespace A
{
    struct B
    {
        using C = int;  // some types
    };
};
```

or

```
struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        using C = int;  // some types
    };
};
```

You need to look into the source code to confirm!